# How to fast delete highlighted code in Xcode

Tags: xcode

[image]

Often times I want to delete a highlighted code or lines, the habit comes from other languages like Java, C++: I would high light the code that I want to delete, then hit the delete key. But in Xcode when I high light, let us say "Dictionary", it would pop up a new frame which tells me the API or something else, and Xcode would switch focus onto the new frame and don't respond to the delete key like in the link above.

What do I do to get this fixed, so that I can highlight something and hit delete key to delete it, or is there a better way to delete stuffs in Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

That's Quick Help. The problem is that you held down the Option key when clicking on the word. Don't do that.

[image]

Comment: I uploaded a photo link in the question session, like when I want to delete somthing it just switch focus automatically whenever I highlight it.

Comment: Well that's what I talk about in my answer. You're holding the Option key when you click. Don't do that and the quick help popover won't appear like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a recent mac or an external Apple trackpad, try just tapping twice instead of pressing.

It seems to me like you're pressing too hard, which the trackpad can detect since it has "force touch", and it shows information about what you are pressing.